# Is there a way to destabilize a character without making them fail a death save?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, character-death

If this is possible, it allows an exploit: destabilize, wait for death save.

- Success -> wait another turn
- Failure/Critical Failure -> Cleric casts *Spare the Dying*, then destabilize again
- Critical Success -> Character is awake at 1 hp

Comment: Related: [Can a zero-HP, unconscious and stable character be woken up prematurely?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56472/can-a-zero-hp-unconscious-and-stable-character-be-woken-up-prematurely/92896#92896)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There is no such way (except maybe suffocation)

PHB, p. 197

> ##### Stabilizing a Creature
>
> A stable creature doesn’t make death saving throws,
> even though it has 0 hit points, but it does remain
> unconscious. **The creature stops being stable, and must start making death saving throws again, if it takes any damage.**

So the only way to stop a creature from being stable is to deal damage to it. (Or, to heal it, but then it is not going from stable to not stable at 0 hits). However, there is also this rule

> **Damage at 0 Hit Points**. If you take any damage while
> you have 0 hit points, you suffer a death saving throw
> failure.

So you can stop them from being stable, but not without them failing a death save. (Thanks to @DarthPseudonym for pointing out that last part.)

#### Suffocation

There is the rule for suffocating which says

> When a creature runs out of breath, it can survive for a number of rounds equal to its Constitution modifier (minimum 1 round). At the start of its next turn, it drops to 0 hit points and is dying.

While it is not clear if you can "drop" from 0 hit points to 0 hit points, if you could not, being unconscious and stable would make you immune to suffocation, which cannot be the way this works.

Assuming you can tell if a creature is dying or not, suffocating takes minutes:

> A creature can hold its breath for a number of minutes
> equal to 1 + its Constitution modifier (minimum of 30 seconds).

So each try will take you typically a minute or more (few characters opt to have a negative modifier on Con). You can expect a critical success only one in 20 times. So on average, at best you can expect this to take a little more than 20 minutes, instead of the 1d4 hours it normally would take to regain a hit point.

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirement of the question. If you take damage while at 0 hit points, you automatically fail a death saving throw, even if you were stable at the time. (See the "Damage at 0 hit points" section just above your quoted text.) If you damage a stabilized creature, they take 1 auto-fail and start making death throws again, which means a natural 1 could kill them instantly (which is what the question is trying to avoid).

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I think you are technically right - we never played it like that but the damage at 0, even though it is in the section aobut making death saves. I'll update, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I mean, it's an important technicality. That initial auto-fail is one of the few things that puts some stakes on unconscious-but-stable and makes small heals worthwhile.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Is suffocation a potential possibility?

Comment: @User23415 Hm... maybe? It says "When a creature runs out of breath, it can survive for a number of rounds equal to its Constitution modifier (minimum 1 round). At the start o f its next turn, it drops to 0 hit points and is dying." Can you drop from 0 to 0? Probably yes, or you would be immune to suffocation when unconscious. Yes, I think this could work. Updating again.

Comment: While the "unconscious" condition does not say it prevents a character from holding their breath, it is ruled as such at the tables at which I play.  Thus for an unconscious character that is suffocating, we jump right to "when a character runs out of breath" rather than waiting the minutes.

Comment: Can you "drop" from 0 to 0?  [Undead fortitude](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/178647/23547) and relentless endurance say yes.  Perhaps this wording in suffocation is meant to get around the "drown healing" technique from 3e?